# Very specific query and its parameters on retrofit2

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am trying to build a speed data query URL using retrofit. Here is how final URL is supposed to be:

```
http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(around:500,50.117633,8.681930)[maxspeed];out;
```

the part I need user input in order to query is:

```
(around:500,50.117633,8.681930)
```

`500` - radius

`50.117633` - latitude

`8.681930` - longitude

I am only a beginner on Retrofit but to my knowledge, `@Query`annotation in Endpoint interface works only on `?data=` and this kind of type query parameters.

This is what I tried doing but it obviously does not work (I tried `@Path` too):

```
 @GET("/interpreter?data=[out:json];way(around:{radius},{latitude},{longitude})[maxspeed];out;")
    Call<SpeedData> getSpeedData(@Query("radius") int radius,
                                 @Query("latitude") double latitude,
                                 @Query("longitude") double longitude);
```

How should I implement it on Retrofit since there is only one query parameter `?data`  when I need to use 3 dynamic parameters inside that `?data` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@GET("/interpreter")
Call<SpeedData> getSpeedData(@Query("data") String data);
```

use a Small function -

```
public String addParseData(String output,String addedData) {
        return output.concat(addedData).concat(";");
```

the data will receive parse String.

Comment: Thanks for answer, unfortunately it does not really work, I somehow need to add a query parameter which would have some parameters inside it. (Query inside a query)

Comment: i c... since there isnt & only ; this is only one long String you need to parse ill update the answer

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work as well. Here is what I pass in my main activity

Call<SpeedData> call = apiService.getSpeedData("[out:json];way(around:500,50.117633,8.681930)[maxspeed];out;");

Comment: what is the response ?? try changing the Call<Speedata> to Call<JsonElement> is it working?

Comment: It does not work. I do not get any response. When I run response.isSuccessful() i get false